# Java array declaration with number sequence

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I'm really new in Java or other programming languages. I have an exercise where I need to make an array with number sequence like: 0,1,2,3,...,K,0,1,2,...,K,0,1,2... until array is full. In exercise are written, that I need to use loop operator "for" for making it. 
If I want to fill an array with only growing numbers, which is equal to the number of element in array, I need to write something like this:

```
for(i=0;i<30;i++)
    A[i]=i;
```

If if the statement of sequence will be mathematically writable, in the place of the "i" after "=" need to write mathematical equation. But there aren't mathematical equation. 
Then I try to make some variations to get the result. I came to the solution, where I can get this sequence done two times. K need to input and there's not problem.

```
for(i=0;i<30 && i<=K;i++)
    if(i<K)
    A[i]=i;
      else
        for(i=K; i<30 && i<=K*2; i++)
            A[i]=i-K;
```

Then I try to initialize "n"  add "n" in the place of the number "2". And in every loop increase "n" by 1. And the works only first part of code.

How to make loop like this with the "for" operator? 
I really want to understand, not only get solution and go further to next task.
Thanks, 
Karlis.

Comment: "there aren't mathematical equation. " I would just use `A[i] = i % (K+1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using modulo operator

```
for(i=0;i<30;i++) A[i]=i%(k+1);
```